# SQL query to retrieve records closest to timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to retrive the records from a table in my MySQL database, where:

- the *timestamp* is the closest to a variable I provide; and,
- grouped by the fields keyA, keyB, keyC and keyD

I've hard coded the variable as below to test this, however can not get the query to work.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37fad2/1)

My current schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE dataHistory (
          timestamp datetime NOT NULL,
          keyA varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          keyB varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          keyC varchar(25) NOT NULL,
          keyD varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          value int NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (timestamp,keyA,keyB,keyC,keyD)
          );

INSERT INTO dataHistory
    (timestamp, keyA, keyB, keyC, keyD, value)
VALUES
    ('2016-05-12 04:15:00', 'value1', 'all', 'value2', 'domestic', 96921),
    ('2016-05-12 04:05:00', 'value1', 'all', 'value2', 'domestic', 96947),
    ('2016-05-12 04:20:00', 'value1', 'all', 'value2', 'domestic', 96954),
    ('2016-05-12 04:15:00', 'value1', 'all', 'value3', 'domestic', 2732),
    ('2016-05-12 04:10:00', 'value1', 'all', 'value3', 'domestic', 2819),
    ('2016-05-12 04:20:00', 'value1', 'all', 'value3', 'domestic', 2802);
```

and the query I currently have is:

```
SELECT e.difference, e.timestamp, e.keyA, e.keyB, e.keyC, e.keyD, e.value
FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, '2016-05-12 04:11:00', d.timestamp) as difference, d.timestamp, d.keyA, d.keyB, d.keyC, d.keyD, d.value
    FROM dataHistory d
    GROUP BY d.keyA, d.keyB, d.keyC, d.keyD) as e;
```

All I can seem to extract from the sample data is the earliest two records and not the two closest to the datetime.
What I receive:

```
difference  timestamp   keyA    keyB    keyC    keyD    value
-10 May, 12 2016 04:05:00   value1  all value2  domestic    96947
-5  May, 12 2016 04:10:00   value1  all value3  domestic    2819
```

I am expecting to see:

```
timestamp   keyA    keyB    keyC    keyD    value
May, 12 2016 04:15:00   value1  all value2  domestic    96921
May, 12 2016 04:10:00   value1  all value3  domestic    2819
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Please make sure which DB you are using SQL or MYSQL. It seems like you are using MYSQL.

Comment: Apologies, this is a MYSQL DB.

Comment: I am not sure about MYSQL but in MSSQL you have to first find the max date after groping and then use self join. May be it helps you.

Comment: If you pass 2016-05-12 04:11:00 then how closest you want? 04:05 or 04:16?

Comment: Passing 2016-05-12 04:11:00 and find the closest either higher or lower so the record matching 04:15:00 is higher and would be returned as it is only 4 minutes away for one set of data and the record matching 04:10:00 as it is -1 minutes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT e.difference, e.timestamp, e.keyA, e.keyB, e.keyC, e.keyD, e.value
FROM (SELECT ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, '2016-05-12 04:11:00', d.timestamp)) as difference, d.timestamp, d.keyA, d.keyB, d.keyC, d.keyD, d.value
    FROM dataHistory d
    ORDER BY difference) as e
GROUP BY e.keyA, e.keyB, e.keyC, e.keyD;
```

This query is returning the values you want.

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to do the job the most simply. I'll have to spend a bit of time walking through exactly what happens here.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
SELECT
  TIMESTAMPDIFF (MINUTE , '2016-05-12 04:15:00' , MainTable.timestamp) AS Difference ,
  MainTable.timestamp ,
  MainTable.KeyA ,
  MainTable.KeyB ,
  MainTable.KeyC ,
  MainTable.KeyD ,
  MainTable.value
FROM
  dataHistory AS MainTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  dataHistory AS SecondaryTable
ON
  MainTable.KeyA = SecondaryTable.KeyA
AND
  MainTable.KeyB = SecondaryTable.KeyB
AND
  MainTable.KeyC = SecondaryTable.KeyC
AND
  MainTable.KeyD = SecondaryTable.KeyD
AND
  ABS (TIMESTAMPDIFF (MINUTE , '2016-05-12 04:15:00' , MainTable.timestamp)) > ABS (TIMESTAMPDIFF (MINUTE , '2016-05-12 04:15:00' , SecondaryTable.timestamp))
WHERE
  SecondaryTable.timestamp IS NULL;
```

---

Guy Glantser,
Data Professional,
Madeira - Data Solutions,
http://www.madeiradata.com

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously expecting some magic to happen here. You group by some fields and select the column `timestamp` and its difference to the current time. And somehow you think you should get the closest time to now. Why? Why should this happen? You are not telling the DBMS to do that. You are simply letting it pick one of the matching timestamps arbitrarily. To pick a particular value per group, you need an aggregate function, e.g. `MIN` to get a minimum value.

You need two steps:

**First step:** Find the minimum timestamp difference to now per group.

```
select 
  keya,
  keyb,
  keyc,
  keyd,
  min(abs(timestampdiff(minute, '2016-05-12 04:11:00', d.timestamp))) as difference
from datahistory 
group by keya, keyb, keyc, keyd;
```

**Second step:** With the query from the first step, find the matching records for each of these minimum differences.

```
select 
  best.difference, 
  dh.timestamp, 
  best.keyA, 
  best.keyB, 
  best.keyC, 
  best.keyD, 
  dh.value
from
(
  select 
    keya, keyb, keyc, keyd,
    min(abs(timestampdiff(minute, '2016-05-12 04:11:00', timestamp))) as difference
  from datahistory 
  group by keya, keyb, keyc, keyd
) best
join datahistory dh 
  on  dh.keya = best.keya and dh.keyb = best.keyb 
  and dh.keyc = best.keyc and dh.keyd = best.keyd
  and abs(timestampdiff(minute, '2016-05-12 04:11:00', dh.timestamp)) = best.difference
order by best.keyA, best.keyB, best.keyC, best.keyD;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6004b/10

(Replace `'2016-05-12 04:11:00'` with `now()` in your real query.)